# Mouselag under Ubuntu 16.04. What can I do?

Tags: 16.04

How can I get rid off my mouselag under Ubuntu 16.04? 
The lag is not related to firefox or a webbrowser. Graphic card is regognized correctly.

```
nuc@nuc:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for nuc: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: I read that the graphics are is recognized, but is it being used?  Can you execute `sudo lshw -c video` and append the results of that command to your question, please?

Comment: Hi. I've added the output above.

Comment: I didn't see much else related to laggy mice:  One indicated the problem was radio interference with a wireless mouse, another indicated a [pcie issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133618/ubuntu-12-04-questionable-ram-usage-mouse-lags-windows-fade-slowly-and-program), and another looked at [specific mouse settings](http://askubuntu.com/questions/208304/jerky-mouse-movements)

Comment: I'm using a wifi mouse. What could cause the interference?

Comment: Bluetooth, microwave, home phones (the radio kind), cell phone, sparkplugs on lawnmower engines.......